# Highcharts, radar chart issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts, radar-chart

I have problems with this radar chart, I'm trying that the items how are the same color (financial e.g.) linkd to the another one, for instance, financial model and sponsor/development should be linked, but no. In excel works fine, this is the code:

```js
$(function () {
   
   $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            polar: true,
            type: 'line'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Budget vs spending',
            x: -80
        },

        pane: {
            size: '80%'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Sponsor/Developer', 'SPA', 'SPV', 'Legal DD','Legal contracts', 'Environmental license',
                'Grid connection license', 'Construction License', 'Generation License', 'Mining rights',
                'Suite Studies/License', 'Property/terrain', 'Technical studies', 'EPC', 'Financial model'],
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            lineWidth: 0                        
        },

        yAxis: {
            gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
            lineWidth: 0,
            min: 0            
        },

        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
        },

        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 70,
            layout: 'vertical'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Legal',           
            data: [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
            pointPlacement: 'on',
            color: "#206ef0",

        }, {
            name: 'Development',            
            data: [null, null, null, null, null, 4,4,4,4,4,4,null,null,null,null],
            pointPlacement: 'on',
            color: "#f07820"
        },
        {
            name: 'Technical',            
            data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,4,4,4,4],
            pointPlacement: 'on',
            color : "#37ce4c"
        },
        {
            name: 'Financial',
            data: [4, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 4],            
            pointPlacement: 'on',
            color: "#dfdd19"
        }
    ]

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 500px"></div>
```

I think there must be one property but I can't find it.
I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: You can use [linkedTo](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.linkedTo) option.

Comment: Thank you for response. It doesn't work and also one legend becomes hidden.

Comment: I mean, the idea is that should be a yellow line between financial model and sponsor development and an orange line between Property/terrain and Suite Studies/License. Thank you :)